# Instantiate Class using namespaces

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I have a function file, in which I put an __autodload() function. For my classes I want to use namespaces, since I'm learning about them. In the folder `lib/` I have a DB class and a Test-User class. Code of those reads as follows:

DB.class.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Lib;

class DB
{
    public $db;

    function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
    {
        $this->db = new MySQLi($host, $username, $password, $database);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Connect error');
        }
    }
}
```

User.class.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Lib;

class User
{
    private $_db;

    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->_db);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

At this moment, my index file looks like this:

```
<?php

include 'functions.inc.php';

$db = new DB('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$user = new User($db);
$user->test();
```

And I'm getting the error `Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tplsys\index.php on line 5`

I've also tried `$db = new \App\Lib\DB()` and `$db = new App\Lib\DB()`, but it's always the same result... autoload function looks like this:

```
function __autoload($className)
{
    if (!file_exists('lib/' . $className . '.class.php')) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        require_once 'lib/' . $className . '.class.php';
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I got it working with the help and links provided by sectus. The code now looks like this:

index.php

```
<?php
include 'functions.inc.php';

spl_autoload_register('autoload');

$db = new \Lib\DB('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$user = new \Lib\User($db);
$user->test();
```

autoload function:

```
function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.class.php';

    require $fileName;
}
```

Classes:

```
<?php

namespace Lib;

class DB
{
    public $db;

    function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
    {
        $this->db = new \MySQLi($host, $username, $password, $database);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysql_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

}
```

I had to rename the namespace to Lib\ since it would look for app/lib/class.php otherwise... I'll just have to play with that a bit. Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: That is not your whole `index.php` file, is it? I think we're missing some vital namespace declarations here.

Comment: Use spl_register_autoload instead.

Comment: @deceze I'm embarassed to say yes, this is my whole index.php... I don't really know how it's done correctly, it's just how I interpret the stuff from the PHP Manual...

Comment: Since there's no `namespace` declaration in `index.php`, it should be looking for `DB`, not `App\Lib\DB`. This is strange.

Comment: @sectus I just did so, but that was not the solution (I'll keep it however, so thanks for that input :) )

Comment: @deceze my bad... It DOES look for DB and not for App\Lib\DB... If I declare the namespace, I looks for App\Lib\DB and if I call the class like `new App\Lib\DB()`, then it, of course looks for that. I edited the post.... Sorry for the confuzzlings

Comment: Is your autoload function in the root (\\) namespace?

Comment: The autoload is not in a namespace, no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use class with namespace with namespaces or [aliases](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

```
<?php

include 'functions.inc.php';

$db = new DB('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');// your DB class has no namespace
$user = new \App\Lib\User($db);               // <--- namespace added
$user->test();
```

And function `__autoload($className)` receive full class name (with namespace). So, when your `__autoload` function will execute it will recieve strings: `'DB'`, `'App\Lib\User'`.

You should read about [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) and use this implementation instead of yours.

Comment: If I add the namespace to the instantiation, it gives me the same error with `App\Lib\DB`. And I'm not really sure how this PSR-0 is implemented, sorry, still learning... Do I write this autoload function as they describe it and then use spl_autoload_register to register it?

Comment: @PatrickManser, when you start to use `App\Lib\DB` $className in __autoload function became `App\Lib\DB`, so you trying to include file `'lib/App\Lib\DB.class.php'`

Comment: I've used the autoload function described in the link you provided. It can find the DB class now (which actually IS in the same namespace as User... I somehow forgot that, I'm gonna edit my post again... sorry for that.. silly me)... But it can't find the User class...

Comment: I forgot to add the '`.class.php`' to the function... now it can't find DB again... Sometimes it's frustrating to be a noob

Comment: Okay, I'm getting closer... It's a matter of the autoload function now, I think :)

Comment: Now it works with your help and the links provided! thank you :)